# Change value of formula in excel on dragging

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a special condition. I have two variables in my formula.

```
=A1+B1
```

Now, when I drag it vertically I want to change the value of A and on dragging horizontally I want to change the value of B. I don't want to change column. Ever.
**For example**:
[image: Sample image]

How do I do it?

Comment: I think more information is needed. What kinds of values are you dealing with? If they are simply reference values you may be able to achieve that with formulas, but since "dragging" is a cursor (or mouse input) function you'll probably have to address this with a VBA script. To my knowledge there aren't any "formulas" or functions built into Excel that deal with mouse input logic.

Comment: @kyle_engineer : the values change in dragging vertically.....And applying the $ I can freeze them as well...But how do I do it for just one variable?!

Comment: You just want A1+B1 or do you have another formula using it? can you give more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))+$B1
```

It will adjust as you asked in both directions.

Comment: Actually, my formula is:
COUNTIF(A1:F1,B1)
where values of A and F need to change vertically and B changes horizontally....

Comment: It's funny how the answer to my new problem derives from both of your answers.:
=COUNTIF(INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(B:B)):INDEX($F:$F,COLUMN(B:B)),$B1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute references for A1 in the first column:
`=$A$1+B1`
and drag it down it will be:
`=$A$1+B2` in the next row and B3 in the next ...

For the second column use:
`=$A$2+B1`
and drag it down

Another method is by using indirect:
`=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN(A1)),INDIRECT("B"&ROW(A1)))`
and you can drag it Horizontally and vertically

Comment: One note: INDIRECT is volatile and will recompute any time Excel recomputes regardless if the underlying data has changed or not.  INDEX is not volatile and will only recompute if the data changes.  A full sheet of INDIRECT will slow the re-compute time of Excel.