# Change formula on dragging

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a special condition. I have three variables in my formula.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,A84)
```

Now, when I drag it vertically I want to change the value of the first parameter i.e. A:F and on dragging horizontally I want to change the value of second parameter i.e. A84. I don't want to change column. Ever.
**For example**:
[image: Sample image]

How do I do it?

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1211716/change-value-of-formula-in-excel-on-dragging) solves the issue for another formula.
Perhaps the solution would look something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(A:A)):INDEX($F:$F,COLUMN(F:F)),$A85)
```

Comment: Basic Excel: put a $ sign before the part that you don't want to change.

Comment: @Aganju: That will prevent it from getting changed when I drag it horizontally as well !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(B:B)):INDEX($F:$F,COLUMN(B:B)),$A86)
```

Another solution would be doing the same using `Indirect()` function.

Answer (score 2):

When excel automatically changes cell references, it will keep a cell locked if you add a $ in front.

So To lock the reference of A1 to its cell regardless of horizontal or vertical movement, you use $A$1.

If you want to make the rows change, but not the columns, You'll change the A1 reference to $A1.

If you want to make the columns change, but keep the rows the same, you change the A1 reference to A$1.

In your example that would make your formula:

```
=CountIf($A$1:$F$1,$A84)
```

Do note, this means you have to manually change the row counter because Excel just doesn't work that way. So you can do it per row, but then have to alter the first cell before transposing it to the right.

Comment: That will prevent it from getting changed when I drag it horizontally as well !!!

Comment: No it doesn't. You have to place the $ at the right place to make it work. I added the formula for you that you would need.

Comment: Tried and tested. Adding $ before a value will ensure that the value is not changed by dragging in either direction. I want to change different variables in different directions. 
The formula that you have provided does not change values of $A1:$F1 or dragging horizontally.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/1211716/change-value-of-formula-in-excel-on-dragging

Comment: Please have a closer look at my answer. I know excel inside out, and if this answer is not what you're looking for, then your question is incorrect. But yeah, I basically say what that answer is saying too. I even added your formula in my answer.

Comment: You may know excel but you seriously need to work on your ego inside-out. Do yourself a favor and copy it in excel and drag it either way. Perhaps you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: I now finally see that the rows for the first are not altered. So another $ is needed then. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I have actually copied your formula and tested it in excel. The values of A1:F1 do NOT change on dragging horizontally.

Comment: In the new formula, the values won't change at all on dragging horizontally.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer. Excel doesn't have support for this.

Comment: Maybe. But it does support the same operation for addition.
https://superuser.com/questions/1211716/change-value-of-formula-in-excel-on-dragging

Comment: Actually, it is possible. And there are multiple ways of doing that.